# Java - Android Studio - Database returns column name and not the message in the column

Tags: java, android, database

Having a weird issue I've spent some time on where I enter a message into a chat app. The message goes into an arrayList as well as a database. When I leave the chat part of the app I want to be able to return and insert the existing messages in the database into the arrayList so they are visible.

When I re-enter the chat portion of the app all I get is "KEY_MESSAGE" instead of the actual message I have typed.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

```
public class ChatWindow extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
Button sendButton;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); // arrayList to hold   "chat"
ChatDatabaseHelper Cdb;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_window);


    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.chatListView);
    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    final ChatAdapter messageAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    Cdb = new ChatDatabaseHelper(this);

    Cursor cursor = Cdb.getMessages();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Cdb.KEY_MESSAGE)));
    }


    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String chatText =  editText.getText().toString(); // changing editText to String
                arrayList.add(chatText); // adding the string from EditTest to arrayList

                boolean isInserted =  Cdb.insertData(chatText); // inserting the message text into the database
                if(isInserted = true)
                    Toast.makeText(ChatWindow.this,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(ChatWindow.this,"Message not Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               editText.setText(" ");

            }

        });




}
// for loop class.
class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{ // custom adapter class // when youc all the adapter it forms the for loop for you.

    public ChatAdapter(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, 0);
    } // default constructor

    // method to return the number of rows that will be in your array
    public int getCount(){ // will tell how many times to run a for loop

        return arrayList.size(); //will return the size of the array
    }

    public String getItem(int position){

        return arrayList.get(position); // will return the item at position
    }

    // getview method
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater Inflater = ChatWindow.this.getLayoutInflater(); // an inflater inflates the xml layout into a view.
        View result = null;
        if(position%2 == 0){ // if position number in the array is odd do this, if number is even, do this.
            result = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_incoming, null); // depending on the position, show layout incoming

        } else {
            result = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_outgoing,null); // depending on the position, show layout outgoing

        }

        TextView message = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.messageText); // creating a message of type TextView connected to messageText
        message.setText(getItem(position));                                 // the messageText is the input typed in.

        return result; // return the view which is the Inflater.


    }
} // end of chat adapter class

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Cdb.close();
    String ACTIVITY_NAME = "ChatWindow";
    Log.i(ACTIVITY_NAME,"In onDestroy()");
}



}
```

This is my Database Helper Class:

```
public class ChatDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Chats.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "chatMessages";
public static final int dbVersion = 1;
public static final int KEY_ID = 0;
public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";


public ChatDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, dbVersion);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " +TABLE_NAME+ "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+KEY_MESSAGE+" text)" );
    Log.i("ChatDataBaseHelper","Calling OnCreate");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
    Log.i("ChatDataBaseHelper","Calling OnUpgrade, oldVersion=" + oldVersion + "newVersion" + newVersion);
}

public boolean insertData(String message){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // creating the database
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    try {

        contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}



public Cursor getMessages(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // creating the database
    Cursor msg = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME,null);

    return msg;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead `Cursor msg = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME,null)`, you have to use something similar tho this:

```
public String createDBandReturnValue(){
    SQLiteDatabase banco = context.openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE_NAME", DATABASE_ACESS, null);//DATABASE_ACESS=0,1 or 2
    Cursor cursor = banco.query("TABLE_NAME", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    String str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_RETURN"));
}
```

Remember to close de connection after. This snipet it's all you need...

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it for me. I ended up clearing the data from the app, debugged again and it worked fine. The app was holding onto some of the "old" database that wasn't working properly. 

Thank you for the reply though!